# Creating 2 D arrays dynamically in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I want to create 2-d arrays dynamically in Perl. I am not sure how to do this exactly.My requirement is something like this-

```
@a =([0,1,...],[1,0,1..],...)
```

Also I want to name the references to the internal array dynamically. i.e. I must be able to refer to my internal arrays with my chosen names which I will be allocating dynamically.
Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a dynamically generated variable name in Perl's strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434333/using-a-dynamically-generated-variable-name-in-perls-strict-mode)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you mean by _name_ and what should be _dynamic_ about them? Maybe include an example, even if it has wrong syntax. Right now I think you don't want to do what Abhi believes, but I could be wrong. If it's what he suggests, then don't do it. It will cause you loads of grieve. But we'd need a better explanation to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a tree/hash of arrays.  Use references to achieve this.

Example of hash of array of array:

```
$ref = {};
$ref->{'name'} = [];
$ref->{'name'}[0] = [];
$ref->{'name'}[0][1] = 3;
```

This could be dynamic if required.  Make sure you initialise what the reference is pointing at.

Comment: In my practice, I prefer to use arrays of pointers, e.g. $ref->{'name'}->[0]->[1], as you will always pass these  things as pointers to functions and will not copy the data contained within - it will save you a lot of memory and performance on huge arrays.

Comment: @mickvav $ref->{'name'}->[0]->[1] is exactly the same as $ref->{'name'}[0][1]

Answer (score 0):

Example array of array references:

```
my @x;
$x[$_] = [0..int(rand(5)+1)] for (0..3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some kind of loop?

```
for (...) {
    my @subarray = ...;
    push @a, \@subarray;
}
```

You could also do

```
for (...) {
    push @a, [ ... ];
}
```

If it's actually a foreach loop, you could even replace it with a `map`.

```
my @a = map { ...; [ ... ] } ...;
```